# Dynamic Programming Algorithm (MinCost buying Apples)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Hello I am trying to build a dynamic programming solution for the following problem :

Given that a family consumes 2kg of apples per day, the apples last 10 days  and the price of the kg of apples per day on day i is p[i] , I have to find the minimum cost so the family does not run out of apples .

Without the 10 days limit i have come up with the solution , that i make a new array :

```
locmin=p[1]
for i=2 to n 
if locmin>=p[i] then c[i]=p[i]
else locmin=p[i] c[i]=p[i]
and then 
OPT[1]=c[i]
OPT(i)=OPT[i-1]+2*c[i] (well not so much of dynamic programming but it is O(n)) .
```

When putting 10 days limitation into account i come up with with a c[i,10] matrix where i store the lowest values of previous 10 days window the same manner as before  for every i-10,i and come up with the solution

```
OPT(i)=OPT[i-1]+2*min(p[i,j]) 0<j<=10
```

.
O(n^2) solution 
Any ideas ?

Comment: your second solution's complexity is 10*n which is O(n)

Comment: Yes i just realized later  since 10 days is a constant

Comment: "Any ideas" is a quite broad question. Is there still a (specific) question?

Answer (score 0):

We can do `O(n)` not just for 10 days but for an arbitrary sized window. Let's take one day at a time. Each day, the family eats 2kg of apples. What's the price of *only* these two `kg`? Clearly, it's `2 * best_price`, where `best_price = min(p[i-9...i])`.

Let's keep a stack. If a price is higher we add to the stack, if it's lower, we pop the stack till a lower earlier price or the stack is empty, then add the new price. The first element in the stack will be the best choice, and it will get replaced by the next element in the stack when it expires.